# LINQ To Entity - With Many to Many Relationship - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following tables in SQL:

Users (UserID, Email)
Roles (RoleID, RoleName)
UsersInRoles (UserID, RoleID)

I want to bring back a list of all Roles and a field which says whether that role has been assigned to a particular user.

In SQL I would do this using the below query:

```
SELECT R.RoleID, RoleName, CASE WHEN ISNULL(UIR.UserID, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM Roles R
LEFT JOIN UsersInRoles UIR ON R.RoleID = UIR.RoleID AND UserID = 2
```

My entity model hides the UsersInRoles table and instead creates a navigation property in each of the Users and Roles entities to link the two.

I'm trying to write a similar LINQ to Entity query but have not been able to.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to perform is an outer join with LINQ.

You can find an example here:
http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx

Here is how you would do it in your case:

```
var query = from r in db.Roles
            from u in db.Users
            join uir in u.Roles on r.RoleID equals uir.RoleID into outer
            from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where u.UserID == 2
            select new
            {
              RoleID = r.RoleID, 
              RoleName = r.RoleName,
              IsInRole = (o != null)
            }
```

**UPDATE**

- Fixed error in query

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method *project* the list of roles  into [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) that contain the fields you're interested in:

```
Dim results = roles.Select(Function(r) New With _
    { _
        .Id = r.RoleId, _
        .Name = r.RoleName, _
        .IsAssigned = r.Users.Any(Function(u) u.UserId = 2) _
    }
```

In case you want to avoid subqueries, you could express the left outer join in LINQ:

```
Dim results = From r In roles
              Group Join u In users On r.RoleId Equals u.RoleId
              Into assignedUsers = Group _
              From au In assignedUsers.DefaultIfEmpty()
              Select New With _
              { _
                  .Id = r.RoleId, _
                  .Name = r.RoleName, _
                  .IsAssigned = If(au Is Nothing, False, au.UserId = 2) _
              }
```

Comment: works great, but this will perform a sub query for each role.

Comment: @ntziolis Are you sure? Sometimes Entity Framework is smart enough to convert such LINQ expressions to SQL joins. Try profiling your application with something like the SQL Profiler or [Entity Framework Profiler](http://efprof.com).

Comment: just checked again via LINQPad and the resulting SQL is using an `EXISTS` subquery as expected

Comment: @ntziolis I updated my answer with an example that uses a left join expressed with LINQ.

Comment: nice one, boy the VB syntax looks strange by now .. and that's even though I started out with VB.NET :)

Comment: The join is joining on RoleID and UserID? Roles or Users do not have a common field.

Comment: @user1244893 In this case try the first solution, which doesn't involve foreign keys but uses the navigation properties instead.